# asp.net mvc 5 send two parametrs to controller from ajax scrypt

Tags: asp.net, ajax, datetime, parameters, asp.net-mvc-5

In my view I have:

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.From, new { htmlAttributes = new {id = "fromEdit", @class = "form -control", @style = "width:300px" } })

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.To, new {htmlAttributes = new { id = "toEdit", @class = "form-control", @style = "width:300px"}})
```

and I need call at a controller action with two DatetTime parameters from a scrypt:

```
    <script>
        var dataToSend = {
            startDate: $("#fromEdit").getDate,
            endDate: $("#toEdit").getDate
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": RootUrl + "SalesDetailsReport/GetSalesDetailReport",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "data": dataToSend ,
                    "dataType": "json"
                },
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "data": "Date", "autoWidht": true },
                    { "data": "Client", "autoWidht": true },
                    { "data": "Product", "autoWidht": true },
                    { "data": "Costs", "autoWidht": true },
                    { "data": "Profit", "autoWidht": true },
                    { "data": "ProfitMarginPercentage", "autoWidht": true },
                    { "data": "Amount", "autoWidht": true },



                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

in my controller:

```
public ActionResult GetSalesDetailReport(DateTime pFrom , DateTime pTo)
```

something is wrong (or everithing) , because in the prperties of my browser i see :

GetSalesDetailReport?_=1477245791871 500 (Internal Server Error)

and the controller action is never called.#

Thanks for your time guys !

Comment: ok , with this change in the properties of my browser i can see:http://localhost:59798/SalesDetailsReport/GetSalesDetailReport?pFrom=23%2F10%2F2016%2019%3A43%3A31&pTo=23%2F10%2F2016%2019%3A43%3A31&_=1477248233768 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) .Looks like I'm reading the date time in the wrong format. Thanks

Comment: And the message of the browser is : The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'pFrom' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetSalesDetailReport(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' in 'ERPPrismaMVC5.Controllers.SalesDetailsReportController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Answer (score 0):

Your action method parameters are `pFrom` and `pTo`. So make sure you are the js object you are sending has the same property name.

```
var dataToSend = {
                  pFrom: $("#fromEdit").val(),
                  pTo:  $("#toEdit").val()
                }
```

Comment: After this change I'm sending this in the url:

Comment: After this change I'm sending this in the url: pFrom=23%2F10%2F2016%2020%3A23%3A01& and because the controller is not receiving the rights parameter is nor calling at the Action. Thanks

Comment: how do you know controller is not receiving the parameter ? Did you put a breakpoint and verify the values ?

Comment: Yes I did, i put a breakpoint at the begining and alos the browser is telling me : The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'pFrom'. I think that take null baceau can solve the type. Any idea ?

Comment: May be your inputs did not have value when the call is made. Try replacing the values for `pFrom` and `pTo` to some hardcoded date strings (Ex : `10/10/2001`) and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, I'm receiving null, but the value is set before call the view in the controller i can also see the text in the editfor in the breakpoint. Sorry, but I'm a beginer on this. Thanks

Comment: Move the `dataToSend ` object creation inside the document ready method.

Comment: I found the solution: replacing   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.From for    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.From and magicall works ! Thanks for see my garbage mate